# Android, dynamically adjust the z-index of a button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 5 buttons on my activity. When a user touches any of them, the button will play an animation which is roughly twice the size of the button itself. When the active button grows/animates, it will overlap the non-active buttons...and sometimes be hidden behind (usually on the edges)

Is there a way I can dynamically adjust something similar to z-index for the button in animation? I already have the logic set up, just don't know the name of a function/if it exists to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [bringChildToFront()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#bringChildToFront%28android.view.View%29) on the surrounding Layout.